# Finding solenoid box

Tags: sprinkler-system

Hello I have an err 1 on my rain bird controller and all the zones work except for one and two which are in the same place could this be a solenoid gone bad. If so I have found the wire that runs out of the controller does this run to the solenoid box?

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to Stack exchange Brandon. Have you had any frost recently, this often causes damage to solenoid valves in irrigation systems? I would work out which pipes should water the broken zones and trace those back to the solenoid. This solenoid is most likely the faulty part and should be replaced.

Comment: It has been warmer here as of recent I'm actually trying to locate my solenoid box which I am have a tough time finding. I found the wire tuning from my controller does that run directly to the solenoids?

Comment: what's the model number of your rain bird controller?